# How to create Play Store like nested tab bar?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I create a nested Tab Bar like the new Google Play Store app with two section one above the other.

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzLhJ.jpg)

I'm very new to android. So I have no idea on how to approach this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: create `tabbar` , inside first tab's `fragment` create another `tabbar`